# How to reload dataTable on change funtion jquery and get value selected option select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

How to reload dataTable on change funtion jquery and get value selected option select?

at first load I set var month to value 0, but when Select change I want to get value of selected option and set var month to value of id="month_report". how to do that?

Here my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    var month = 0;
    var table = $('#dataTables').DataTable({
        responsive:true,
        ajax : {
            url : 'dashboard/report?month='+month,
            data : function(data){
                return data;
            }
        },
        "searching": false,
        columns : [
            {
                data: 'customer',
                searchable : false
            },
            {
                data: 'age',
                searchable : false
            },
            {
                data: 'pbw',
                searchable : false
            },
            {
                data: 'per',
                searchable : false
            },
            {
                data: 'ipo',
                searchable : false
            }
        ]
    });

    $('#month_report').change( function() {
        var month = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
        table.ajax.reload().draw();
    });

});
```

```html
<select name="month" id="month_report">
    <option value="" selected="">Pilih Bulan :</option>
    <option value="1">Januari</option>
    <option value="2">Februari</option>
    <option value="3">Maret</option>
    <option value="4">April</option>
    <option value="5">Mei</option>
    <option value="6">Juni</option>
    <option value="7">Juli</option>
    <option value="8">Agustus</option>
    <option value="9">September</option>
    <option value="10">Oktober</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">Desember</option>
</select>
```

Comment: var month = $(this).val();
$('#month_report').val(month)

Answer (score 2):

Reload data for datatable

try code

```
$('#month_report').change( function() {
    var month = $(this).val();
    table.ajax.url('dashboard/report?month='+month).load();});
```

Answer (score 0):

Following line will give you the selected value of dropdown having id=month_report

```
var month = $("#month_report").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

put your ajax call under '.change (function() {})', call your 'action' method and, eventually, draw your datatable with your circumstances.

More less, it will like this:

```
    $('#month_report').change( function() {
        var month = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
        $.ajax({
        type: 'GET', //'POST'
        url: '@Url.Action("your_action")',
        data: { ID: month },
        success: function (data) {

            //drawing your datatable here....
            $('#dataTables').DataTable({
                 destroy: true,
                 responsive:true,
                 data: data,
                 searching: false,
                 columns : [
                    {data: 'customer', searchable : false},
                    {data: 'age', searchable : false},
                    {data: 'pbw', searchable : false},
                    {data: 'per', searchable : false},
                    {data: 'ipo', searchable : false}]
             });
          }
      });
```

this was [my issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62359062/reload-datatable-after-dropdown-value-changed/62407391#62407391)

Answer (score -1):

```js
$("#month_report").on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val() > 0){
        var month = $(this).val();
        table.ajax.url('dashboard/report?month='+month);
        table.ajax.reload();
    } 
});
```